# Using custom field value in replyTo attribute of messaging:emailTemplate

Tags: visualforce, email-template

Requesting some guidance here.

Say there's a custom field Test__c...can be either text, preferably email field...

Is it at all possible to use that field's value in replyTo ?

Basically trying to make the string that goes into replyTo dynamic....

Thank you for your help!!

cL

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but the question is the same exact one I had this morning. The comments already on this thread aren't helpful, but I was able to piece together a solution. So I want to share because I don't see this question stated clearly anywhere else, nor do I see any solutions to this question stated anywhere else.

When you make a Visualforce template, you associate it with an object.

In this case, let's say your associated object is called "Trump Is Evil"

And let's say that within that object, you have an email field called "Custom Reply To Email" and that is the field you want to be the "ReplyTo" address.

Then your Visualforce template will look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If its a email Field definitely you can use it. But text field i sure cannot be used,even if you try to use it may give you some delivery failure issue when the email address is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a possible way. You can simply create a field (Say, **ReplyTo__c**) in a Custom Setting and reference the same. Something like this:

```
replyTo="{!$Setup.CustomSettings__c.ReplyTo__c}" >
```

Use **$Setup** to access hierarchical custom settings and their field values using dot notation. It would also allow values at Organization level, Profile level and User level.